# Roslyn context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol() returning NULL from InvocationExpression

Tags: vb.net, vb6, roslyn, vb6-migration

Trying to develop an VS extension to help with migration from vb6 to Vb.net using Roslyn.

Unfortunately I am not having much luck with detecting the "DoEvents" expression in my source as I get NULL from my GetDeclaredSymbol during the detection.

My bad coding is......

Register the action:

```
 context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AddressOf ExpressionStatementDec, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression)
```

Try and detect the "DoEvents" expression:

```
Private Sub ExpressionStatementDec(context As SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext)

    Dim GotYou = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(context.Node)

    Dim WhatExpression = context.Node.ToFullString.ToString

    ' Find DoEvents.
    If RemoveWhitespace(WhatExpression) = "DoEvents" Then

        Dim diag = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, GotYou.Locations(0), GotYou.Name)
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diag)

    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried loads of options for trying to get the right type of object for "GotYou" but no luck so far.

Any pointers appreciated :)

**Edit Additional info:**
I have tried GetSymbolInfo but when I am detecting "DoEvents" in the context.Node.ToFullString.ToString I am still not getting anything in the context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(context.Node) as below.

[image]

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Ah so I might have missed an important detail. In your case of migrating from VB6 to VB.NET, are those DoEvents calls pointing to anywhere? Or if you try to compile them are you just getting errors because there is no DoEvents?

Comment: Thanks Jason. Developing a migration tool extension to help us migrate the vast amount of vb6 code we have. In vb6 you have "DoEvents" and the vb.net equivalent is "Application.DoEvents". And yes with the native vb6 code in a vb.net environment it will not compile. So I am wanting to detect "DoEvents" in visual studio and provide a diagnostics lightbulb option to change "DoEvents" to "Application.DoEvents". At the moment I am struggling to get enough info to create a Diagnostic.Create(Rule....

Comment: So if there isn't a DoEvents method in your code somewhere, then there is no symbol for any API from the SemanticModel to return; instead you should be doing what you were doing originally by looking at the text of the expression. Instead you should just use the location of the syntax node then trying to get a symbol to report the location of, which incidentally would be reporting the location of the definition anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at what a invocation is referencing, call GetSymbolInfo not GetDeclaredSymbol.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I had tried GetSymbolInfo but unfortunately I still did not get anything back. Updated my question with more info and screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t have Visual Studio handy in order to get the code, but...

I believe what you want is something like:

```
Dim WhatExpression = TryCast(CType(context.Node, InvocationExpressionSyntax).Expression, IdentifierNameSyntax)?.Identifier.Text
```

This isn’t all of it, you could be dealing with a memberaccessexpression, in which case it’s probably not what you are looking for.  The options would be a bit easier to handle with pattern matching in C#, but that’s the general idea.  You don’t need the semantic tree at this point, because you first want to verify that you are dealing with the right text.  Once you’ve got that, you can see where it comes from and whether it is something you need to deal with.  Getting the semantic model is expensive, no reason to do so when (outside of your unit test) it is rarely going to be needed.